# Wrong HTTP redirect on facebook app oauth popup

Tags: facebook, facebook-oauth

i have problem with wrong redirection after pressing "Play Now" button on the authorization popup.

The app is hosted on my server (iis) at https://www.xxx.com/mygame

Canvas page URL is https://apps.facebook.com/myfacebookgame/

The actual redirect link is: apps.facebook.com/myfacebookgame/mygame which now returns error (mvc app).

It worked fine since yesterday (for the past 2 years).

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: what is the error? what do you mean by MVC app. If the dialog redirects with an error, the body tells you what the error is. I've done this recently. What URL are you targeting for the authentication?

Comment: its a mvc app (web lobby for hosting flash game). error (mygameController not found) occurs because added string to redirect url (/mygame) - it should be as its set for canvas page URL (without /mygame).

Comment: i notice, that facebook sets a url (state parameter in url) which contain that additional string in the redirect url. What could cause this?